# .data assigned attribute selector in jQuery 1.7.1

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a div with a class .imagepicker that is assigned an imgPickerId via `.data("imgPickerId, somevalue)` call. I need to access this particular .imagepicker via jQuery selector.

I have examined several questions on SO and have read several blogs - doesn't work in my case.

Here is how I am trying to select it, along with a chrome debug tools watch proof that it is actually assigned:

[image]

An id is 1914. How do I select it correctly with jQuery 1.7.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
var $picker = $(".imagepicker").filter(function() {
    return $(this).data("imgPickedId") == 1914;
});
```